# Combine two two selected numbers in a combobox to create a date (day and month)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tkinter, combobox

I have two comboboxes named Day and Mounth. By selecting the numbers of both, I would like to merge them (day + month) into a single element called "date", in order to get a date. They must be divided by a period ".", For example 26.12

I get this error: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

```
day = StringVar()
month = StringVar()
date = StringVar()

def data():
    day= combo_day.get()
    month = combo_month.get()
    result = day + '.' + month
    return result


#Day
combo_day = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=6, textvariable=day)
combo_day['values'] = ("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31") 
combo_day.place(x=15, y=150)
combo_day.set("Day")

#Month
combo_month = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=6, textvariable=month)
combo_month['values'] = ("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12") 
combo_month.place(x=105, y=150)
combo_month.set("Month")

#insert in database
def add():

    data_value=data()
    db.insert(aaaa.get(), bbbb.get(), data_value())
```

Comment: Have you looked at using [tkcalendar](https://pypi.org/project/tkcalendar/) instead of comboboxes?

Comment: @jezza_99 Yes, I used it, but the numbers are combined with a "/" and single numbers like 8 serve me in the form of 08. So I preferred to create two simple comboboxes from scratch. I don't need a calendar, just a combination of day and month. Can you help me please? Thanks

Comment: Just use `date = day.get() + '.' + month.get()` after you have chosen the day and month, for example inside a callback of a button.

Comment: Why do you use `data_value()` as `data_value` is just a string?

Comment: @acw1668 And how could I solve? I used your kind suggestion earlier. I don't know if I spelled it correctly :) result = day + '.' + month

Comment: Just use `data_value` instead of `data_value()` in `db.insert(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Maybe you got confused writing in the comment. If you were perhaps referring to replacing data with data_value (), it doesn't work that way. I tried. it does not work

Comment: No. I am not confused in my last comment.  Once again replace `data_value()` by `data_value` (i.e. remove the `()`).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [tkcalendar](https://pypi.org/project/tkcalendar/) as an option for date inputs in tkinter, as it is easy to use and gives a date as a `datetime` object. However, doing what you want is very achievable without using tkcalendar. You just need to add a trace to both `StringVar` that defines `date` when both Comboboxes have been selected.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# StringVars, day and month lists
day = tk.StringVar()
month = tk.StringVar()
days = [str(i).rjust(2, "0") for i in range(1, 32)]
months = [str(i).rjust(2, "0") for i in range(1, 13)]

# Trace callback, return date if both fields filled out, None otherwise
def callback(*args):
    if day.get() in days and month.get() in months:
        date = f"{day.get()}.{month.get()}"
    else:
        date = None
    print(date)

# Trace StringVars
day.trace_add('write', callback)
month.trace_add('write', callback)

# Day combobox
combo_day = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=6, textvariable=day, values=days)
combo_day.place(x=15, y=150)
combo_day.set("Day")

# Month combobox
combo_month = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=6, textvariable=month, values=months)
combo_month.place(x=105, y=150)
combo_month.set("Month")

root.mainloop()
```

**Edit for clarification and how to add `date` to database after it is defined:**

You need to have it as a callback function so that the value of `date` is updated when you change the combobox. You have to insert `date` into the database inside the `callback` function, as otherwise it will try to write `date` to the database when you launch the GUI, **not** when your user selects dates. You should read more about [event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) if you don't understand why you need to use a function for this.

Comment: thanks, you were kind, but there is one thing that does not come back to me. "date" I would like to insert it into the database. I noticed that you wrote it inside a function. can I still save "date" in the database or must date be out of the function so that I can recall it and insert it in the database?

Comment: @DavidTorres0101 I have edited my answer to include more information for you

Comment: I thank you. But being new to Python, I find your answer a little difficult in some places. I changed my code by adding more useful stuff to it. I would like to stick to my code. In addition to your kind reply which will have educational purpose for both me and the readers of the question, can you help me with my code? Please? I will vote for your answer of course